# Can every true type be reached from the unit type in small steps?

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory

We are playing a game where you start at the unit type and the goal is to reach a given true type.

You can go from your current location to another by writing down a (non-dependent) function of length at most 1000 (the lambda type annotation is not counted in the length).

Can you reach any true type in a finite number of steps?

1000 is pretty arbitrary; it would be interesting to see an analysis for any limit. The type system is Martin-Löf or HoTT.

I expect it to be impossible. There are probably "prime terms" (like there are prime numbers) that cannot be decomposed into smaller pieces.

Comment: Just to check I’m understanding right: To go from $A$ to $B$ (where both are well-formed closed types), you must give a function term $t : A \to B$, such that after recursively erasing all type data in $t$, it has size $≤ 1000$ (or $≤L$ for some fixed $L \in \mathbb{N}$)? Then here’s a trivial constraint: you can only reach types that have some closed term, e.g. you certainly can’t reach the empty type.  But it feels like that’s not the interesting answer you’re after — I guess the question should just be fixed to “can we reach any type-that-has-some-closed-term this way”?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I think that's what OP means by a " true type".

Comment: @ValeryIsaev: Ahh, that makes sense — I thought they just meant “well-formed”.

Comment: By true type I meant an inhabited type

Comment: I am not sure I understand fully correctly your question.

With my understanding, the "prime terms" of MLTT or HoTT are known: they are given by the symbols specified by the rules of the formalized type theory. There is only a finite number of them, so their lengths have an upper bound - say 1000 - and the comparison with prime numbers is limited...
Any normalizable term can be written as a finite composition of such "prime terms" of the theory (some "prime terms" define functions, others constants).

Comment: @L.Garde then the proof of Fermat's Last Theorem can also be written like this?